# Executing query from Apache Calcite to secured ElasticSearch Server (https)

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-calcite

How to express the scheme(https) in the model.json file, this is for connection to Elasticsearch?

The following is the model.js file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultSchema": "elasticsearch",
  "schemas": [
    {
      "type": "custom",
      "name": "elasticsearch",
      "factory": "org.apache.calcite.adapter.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSchemaFactory",
      "operand": {
        "coordinates": "{'127.0.0.1': 9200}",
        "index": "myIndex",
        "useConig": "{}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the following JAVA code I am trying to connect to Elasticsearch:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:", properties);
calciteConnection = conn.unwrap(CalciteConnection.class);
String elasticSchema = Resources.toString(somefile.class.getResource("/model.json"), Charset.defaultCharset());

new ModelHandler(calciteConnection, "inline:" + elasticSchema);

String sql = “select field1 from table1”
statement2 = calciteConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet set = statement2.executeQuery();
```

The get a connection closed exception and I can see in the log that it was trying to connect to http not https(desired).  Where do I mention https in the model file?

Answer (score 0):

Calcite's Elasticsearch adapter doesn't currently support connections via HTTPS. I'd suggest you open up an issue on [Calcite's JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/CALCITE/issues). Or better yet, contribute the necessary code changes yourself :)